# Problem with recursive rar archiving non-ascii filenames

Tags: command-line, lubuntu, ascii, rar

Say I want to create a backup of folder `MainFolder`'s content using `rar`. The command

```
rar a Backup.rar -r MainFolder
```

does the job.

**BUT**, *if a subdirectory contains more than one file named with non-ASCII (?) characters, then* **only one of them is archived and the others get excluded**.

For example, consider the following directory hierarchy (`MainFolder`, `A` and `B` are folders; `a`, `b`, `你` and `好` are files)

```
+MainFolder
   +A
      -a
      -b
      -你
      -好
   +B
      -a
      -b
   -a
   -b
   -你
   -好
```

then the command `rar a Backup.rar -r MainFolder` skips

```
MainFolder/A/好
MainFolder/好
```

while `rar a Backup.rar -r MainFolder/*` still skips

```
MainFolder/A/好
```

Why is it so? Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

For the record, I already encountered some issues with non-ascii characters (see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/228645/114498)) that other Linux distributions seem not to have. Anyway, I use `Lubuntu 12.04`, terminal is `lxterminal` and `echo $BASH_VERSION` returns `4.2.25(1)-release`. `rar` version is `4.00 beta 3`.

Another curiosity: right-clicking on the folder and selecting `Compress...` and then `.rar` still has the same problem. Other options (`zip`, `tar`...) behave correctly.

Comment: I use RAR 4.20 and I don't have this problem. Maybe there is more than only `好` character in the name of that directory.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Thanks for trying it out. What do you mean by 'there is more than only `好` character in the name of that directory'? The directory I tested is exactly as that shown above.

Comment: To check if doesn't contain any others white/special characters, what is the output of `ls -ld 好` and `ls -ld A/好` commands when you are inside `MainFolder`?

Comment: They return just `-rw-rw-r-- 1 radyce radyce 0 Nov 12 23:20 好` [resp. `A/好`].

Comment: This mean that doesn't contain any others characters. Check your rar version; as I told you, I use RAR 4.20 and I don't have this problem.

Comment: Another strange issue is that running `find Main` in `Main`'s parent folder displays everything correctly, but `rar a Backup.rar $(find Main)` still skips every non-ascii filename from the second on in each folder. Really odd isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I think that your command will just work with `UTF-8` enabled in the shell, so all you need to do is enable that. To do this run first the following command:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

To make the change permanently, add the above line in your `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: `LANG` was set to `en_GB.UTF-8`, switching to US didn't solve the problem :(

Comment: @AndreasT Maybe you are experiencing [this bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=108711). See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8859/can-a-gnome-terminal-profile-use-utf-8-by-default.

Comment: @AndreasT And again, update to the last version of rar, which now is 4.20.